# SQLite3 on windows: Convert epoch to normal time

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to convert the following timestamp(in milliseconds since epoch) to normal date-time. Am using sqlite3 on windows xp.

I am using this query:
select datetime((timestamp/86400000)+25569) from table;

(timestamp is the column name which contains the values like 1289325613669,1289325823860,
1289327180545).

I dont seem to be getting the right values. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
select datetime('1289325613', 'unixepoch');
```

The `unixepoch` modifier expects a value in seconds.

Currently, what you provide to datetime is interpreted as a Julian Day number.

The reference for date and time functions is [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)