# Using Sqlite query, Get a Date from stored milliseconds

Tags: java, android, datetime-format, android-sqlite

I am using sqlite database in my application in which I am storing a Date and Time in milli-seconds. Now using Sqlite query I am trying to get this datetime from milliseconds to date in format "yyyy-MM-dd" but not getting a proper result.

I want to do this using a Sqlite query.
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what code you have, and what it is returning? Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327483/sqlite3-on-windows-convert-epoch-to-normal-time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237193/java-convert-milliseconds-to-date

Comment: Didn't try with `SimpleDateFormat` class?

Comment: You can use [Strftime()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630215/retrieve-date-wise-data-from-database-in-android/11638703#11638703)

Comment: @RossC Thanks a lot. Your link has helped me. The datetime method takes the argument in seconds and I had try to set the milliseconds. Thanks again :)

Comment: My pleasure, it's an easy thing to overlook. I still get counting from zero wrong at least once per program I write! Which I shouldn't admit to here!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Datetime` expects epochtime, which is in number of seconds while you are passing in milliseconds. Convert to seconds & apply.

```
SELECT datetime(1346142933585/1000, 'unixepoch');
```

Can verify this from this fiddle

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d41d8/223

Comment: +1 I am sure that this will work.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks a lot. Just one modification is that if we want a time in local timezone then Use this query
`SELECT datetime(1346142933585/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime');`

Comment: @Dharmendra yeah, I thought of mentioning that(you'll note I tested it -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d41d8/224), but I didn't mention it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select strftime("%Y-%m-%d", YOUR_DATE_COL) from .......
```

Comment: Getting wrong result.. I am getting proper format but not getting true value for example I have 1346142933585 milli which is equals to "2012-08-28" but I am getting "1698-19-20".